# Java Code: Variable packageA and packageB might not have been initialized. Help please

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So im still new to java but for the assignment, I need to

This is Challenge 13

**Internet Service Provider**
An Internet service provider has three different subscription packages for its customers:
Package A: For $9.95 per month 10 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour.
Package B: For $13.95 per month 20 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour.
Package C: For $19.95 per month unlimited access is provided.
Write a program that calculates a customer’s monthly bill. It should ask the user to enter the letter of the package the customer has purchased *A, B, or C) and the number of hours that were used. It should then display the total charges.

**Description** Modify the program you wrote for Programming Challenge 13

- so it also calculates and displays the amount of money Package A customers
- would save if they purchased Package B or C, and the amount of money
- Package B customers would save if they purchased Package C. If there would
- be no savings, no message should be printed.

so this is the code that I have printed:

```
package assignment14;

import java.util.*;

public class Assignment14
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String userInput;

        char packageChosen;
        double packageA,packageB,totalHours, totalSavingsAtoB, totalSavingsAtoC, totalSavingsBtoC; 
/*THE ERROR MESSAGE OCCURS IN  THIS LINE FOR THE FIRST packageA AND FOR packageB*/   

        totalSavingsAtoB = (packageA - 13.95);
        totalSavingsAtoC = (packageA - 19.95);
        totalSavingsBtoC = (packageB - 19.95);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which package have you obtain? (Please use A, B, or C)");
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        packageChosen = userInput.charAt(0);


        switch (packageChosen)
        {

            case 'A': 
                System.out.println("What are the total amount of hours used for this month?");
                totalHours = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    if (totalHours <= 10)
                    {
                     packageA = 9.95 * totalHours;
                     System.out.print("For Package A:\nThe total charges for this month is $ " + packageA);
                     System.out.print("\nYou save a total of " + totalSavingsAtoB + "if you chose Package B\n" 
                                     + "and you would have save a total of " + totalSavingsAtoC + "if you chose Package C.");
                    }
                    else

                      packageA = 9.95 + (totalHours * 2.00);
                      System.out.print("For Package A:\nThe total charges for this month is $ " + packageA);

                    if (totalSavingsAtoB > packageA)
                    {
                        totalSavingsAtoB = (packageA - 13.95);
                        totalSavingsAtoC = (packageA - 19.95);
                        System.out.print("\nYou save a total of " + totalSavingsAtoB + "if you chose Package B\n" 
                                     + "and you would have save a total of " + totalSavingsAtoC + "if you chose Package C.");

                    }
                    break;
            case 'B': 
                System.out.println("What are the total amount of hours used for this month?");
                totalHours = keyboard.nextDouble();
                if (totalHours <= 20)
                {
                    packageB = 13.95 * totalHours;
                    System.out.print("For Package B:\nThe total charges for this month is $" + packageB);
                    System.out.print("You would have save a total of " + totalSavingsBtoC + ", if you have chosen Package C.");
                }
                else
                {
                    packageB = 13.95 + (totalHours * 1.00);
                    System.out.print("For Package B:\nThe total charges for this month is $" + packageB);
                    System.out.print("You would have save a total of " + totalSavingsBtoC + ", if you have chosen Package C.");
                }
                if (totalSavingsAtoB > packageA)
                {
                    totalSavingsBtoC = (packageB - 19.95);
                    System.out.print("\nYou save a total of " + totalSavingsAtoB + "if you chose Package B\n" 
                                     + "and you would have save a total of " + totalSavingsAtoC + "if you chose Package C.");

                }
                break;
            case 'C':
                System.out.print("For Package C:\nThe total charge for this is $19.95.");
                System.out.print(" \nThank you for using our service!  " );   
                     break;
            default:
                    System.out.print("Invalid entry, Please try again.");
       }

    }
}
```

The error message I keep getting for packageA and packageB is that these variables might not have been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you use a variable before it has been initialized (like it says). A local variable (such as `packageA` or `packageB` in your case) is not assigned a default value by the compiler.

In other words, its complaining because *it has no idea what you are subtracting 13.95 from* in your line `totalSavingsAtoB = (packageA - 13.95)` (and in the other lines).

So, you need to set `packageA` and `packageB` to some value before using them (maybe 0? Maybe how much the package costs? I don't know).

**Aside**

Just based on context I would guess that those 3 lines that are giving you trouble should go somewhere after you set up the values (I noticed that you are assigning them in each case of the switch).

Comment: Oh i feel stupid.. common sense. Thank you. But now how would I be able to say if (totalHours <= 10) but also if totalSavingsAtoB > packageA then a certain code would run? does java have a AND statement?

Comment: Yes. The AND operator is `&&`. So, your statement would be `(totalHours <= 10 && totalSavingsAtoB > packageA)`. You may want to look at [the Java operators documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: so one more thing, i change the code and everything is working fine, but now the ending part of the code I have to find the savings, but when there is no savings I am getting a negative number. in the code could i do an if statement in the cases like /*if (someVariable > 0)*/ saying that whatever the response will be needs to be greater than zero to execute and if not nothing, if so, where to place this if statement.